# p:layout component not rendered when used in template client

Tags: layout, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I am using JSF 2.0 and PrimeFaces 2.2.1. In my template.xhtml, I have a `ui:insert` component:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
   <h:head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>A page</title>
   </h:head>

   <h:body>
      <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

In myPage.xhtml which uses the above template, I defined a `<p:layout>` component as following:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="./../template/template.xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

   <ui:define name="content">
      <p:layout>
         <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
            Center unit
         </p:layoutUnit>

         <p:layoutUnit position="right" collapsible="true">  
            Right unit
         </p:layoutUnit>  
      </p:layout> 
   </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

When I opened myPage.xhtml, I saw "Center unit" and "Right unit" but I didn't see any layout rendered.

However, when I tried to put the `<p:layout>` component inside the template as following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
   <h:head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>A page</title>
   </h:head>

   <h:body>
      <p:layout>
         <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
            <ui:insert name="center"></ui:insert>
         </p:layoutUnit>

         <p:layoutUnit position="right" collapsible="true">  
            <ui:insert name="right"></ui:insert>
         </p:layoutUnit>  
      </p:layout> 

   </h:body>
</html>
```

everything works perfectly. Any pages that use the 2nd template rendered the component as expected.

I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me what I have done wrong with the 1st template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that it is possible to use `<p:layout>` within `<ui:define>`.

You can use a `<ui:insert>` within a `<p:layoutUnit>` however:

```
<p:layout>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
           <ui:insert name="Center unit" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="right" collapsible="true">
           <ui:insert name="Right unit" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```